# Calendar in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I need to make a functional calendar in javascript, html and css[this is the way it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZd0X.png)

Comment: so, what is preventing you from making the calendar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):)

Comment: I have tried to make the app at first but i dont know how to use grid or flex boxes to make that apperance on the site and also that popup. I can post a link to what i have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this complete guide to flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It should clear things up when building your calendar. If you dont want to read it (I strongly reccomend it), just make the parent container flex, and play around in your browser's devTools.